# Cambiar el valor de input cuando introduzco un numero

Tags: html, controller, angular8

Tengo un input de tipo numérico y quiero que cambie el valor introducido justo cuando lo introduzco. Quiero decir, si introduzco 1 que pinte un -1.
He intentado esto pero no me funciona.

HTML:

```
<input  type="number" class="col-flex-xs-2 category-combo" maxlength="6"  (change)="modelChanged($event)" [ngModel]="inputValue" placeholder="Introduzca importe">
```

TS:

```
public inputValue:number;

modelChanged(event){       
    
    this.inputValue = event.target.value * (-1);    
    
}
```

El problema es que solo funciona cuando "clickeo" fuera del input pero me gustaria que lo haga justo cuando introduzco ese valor

Gracias!

Comment: Prueba de poner `[(ngModel)]="inputValue"` para tener un *two-way binding*.

Comment: Hola @VRoxa, lo he intentado pero no funciona. Gracias!